# Как установить Google Play Music Desktop Player в Fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

Пытаюсь поставить GPMDP в ОС Fedora Workastation 31. Способ который использовал:

```
sudo snap install google-play-music-desktop-player
```

после использования этой команды GPMDP ставится, но не запускается с ошибкой

```
WARNING: cgroup v2 is not fully supported 
yet, proceeding with partial confinement

(google-play-music-desktop-player:3150): 
Gtk-WARNING **: 10:40:11.680: cannot open 
display: :0
```

Удаляю snap пакет, иду на [сайт разработчков](https://www.googleplaymusicdesktopplayer.com/) и скачиваю версию для Fedora x86_64(именно такая у меня стоит).
Далее делаю

```
cd Загрузки
sudo rpm -i google-play-music-desktop-player-4.6.1.x86_64.rpm
```

Пакет устанавливается успешно, но при попытке запуска Возникает
`Ошибка сегментирования, стек сброшен на диск`

Очень хочется использовать именно этот плеер, да и поддержка Fedora на сайте разрабов заявлена. Как поставить?

В Ubuntu 18.04 при скачивании с сайта разраба и установки .deb пакета путем

```
sudo dpkg -i <имя пакета>
```

Недоустанавливаются зависимости но помогает

```
sudo apt install -f
```

Может быть есть в Fedora аналог такой команды, которая установит зависимости для пакета? 
В хэлпе по yum вычитал про

```
sudo yum-builddep <имя пакета>
```

Но попытка им вспользоваться не увенчалась успехом ибо ошибка

```
нет подходящих пакетов: google-play-music-desktop-player
Ошибка: Некоторые пакеты не удалось найти
```

и не понятно, какие именно пакеты не удалось найти. Я б их сам поискал, если б знал какие. Как узнать, какие пакеты нужно доустановить?

UPD:
Использовал

```
sudo yum deplist google-play-music-desktop-player
```

но данная команда ничего не вывела

UPD2:
нашел проблему. В Fedora gnome запускается на Wayland по умолчанию. Переключил на Gnome на xorg при входе в систему, переустановил программу, перезагрузился, все заработало...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ установки данного приложения, через flatpak. На [Flathub оно есть](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.googleplaymusicdesktopplayer.GPMDP). Нормально устанавливается и стабильно работает с Wayland в Fedora 31 Workstation.
Установил и проверил на своей системе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Следом перегрузился в Xorg и проверил там, также всё стабильно работает.
Если репозиторий Flathub ранее не добавлялся на машину, то до установки необходимо будет его добавить:

```
$  flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Далее установка при помощи магазина приложений, или через терминал:

```
$ flatpak install flathub com.googleplaymusicdesktopplayer.GPMDP
```

Запуск через меню, либо с помощью терминала:

```
$ flatpak run com.googleplaymusicdesktopplayer.GPMDP
```